# Reportlab Wrapper

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm looking for a Reportlab wrapper which does the heavy lifting for me. 
I found [this](https://github.com/matthiask/pdfdocument) one, which looks promising.

It looks cumbersome to me to deal with the low-level api of Reportlab (especially positioning of elements, etc) and a library should facilitate at least this part.

My code for creating .pdfs is currently a maintain hell which consists of positioning elements, taking care which things should stick together, and logic to deal with varying length of input strings.

For example while creating pdf invoices, I have to give the user the ability to adjust the distance between two paragraphs. Currently I grab this info from the UI and then re-calculate the position of paragraph A and B based upon the input.

Besides that I look for a wrapper to help me with this, it would be great if someone could point me to / provide a best-practice example on how to deal with positioning of elements, varying lengh of input strings etc.

Comment: [Library recommendations are considered not constructive on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134914/why-are-library-recommendation-questions-prohibited)

Comment: Edited my comment based upon [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134916) answer.

Comment: Platypus is part of ReportLab and it already takes care of wrapping things up pretty well so that you think about objects in your document rather than drawing on a PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

Having tested the lib [PDFDocument](https://github.com/matthiask/pdfdocument), I can only recommend it. It takes away a lot of complexity, provides a lot of helper functions, and helps to keep your code clean. I found [this](https://github.com/matthiask/plata/blob/master/plata/reporting/order.py) resource really helpful to get started.